# makecontext uc_link gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, coroutine, context-switch

I am trying to make a user level thread library like pthreads. I am using the *makecontext()*/*swapcontext()* to do the switching between the threads and while making a context for the thread, I am passing *uctx_main* to the *uc_link* field in the context.

```c
context.uc_stack.ss_sp = thread->c_stack;
context.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(thread->c_stack);
context.uc_link = &uctx_main;
```

However, when my thread terminates, it gives me a segmentation fault. My main program is still running.

Also, can someone please explain what is *uctx_main*? Is it the default context for the main function? Do I need to have a *uctx_main* for every thread that I create? Sorry for asking such a silly question, but I did not find anything on googling it.

Comment: I'm not certain in this case, but if you are going to swap around contexts, everything that you swap in has to have one.  This means that, if the 'main function' is ever to run again after initializing your library, it should to be operating as a thread within your thread library and so must have a context to swap in. T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your reference to `uctx_main` that you are following the example in the [Linux man page for `makecontext()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/makecontext).

In that example, `uctx_main` is the context for the main thread, which is set when calling `setcontext()` to switch to `uctx_func2`.

`uctx_main` isn't special in any way, other than it having been set from the main thread (and being set as the successor to `uctx_func1` in the example).

In general, every thread you create needs to have a context.